# can't open new window on form submit in angular pwa

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have angular pwa app and in a form submit I want to open a new window in browser. By adding _blank just open a tab inside my app

Comment: [ATM that's not possible](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/989). The only workaround that might work in most cases is to have the link you want to open to be hosted in a subdomain (in my case that's `external.example.com`, because it's for external logins)

Comment: it's in a redirect form to an external address

Comment: That's a different case indeed. But wouldn't know the answer rightaway.